# Three dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a simple form that has 3 elements:

- Country
- City
- Site.

I'm doing that with `php`, `mysql` (to get the data) and a script.

I got it to work... sort of...

When I select the country, ie: England, I get the next dropdown populated with english cities but the "site" dropdown isn't populate UNLESS I manually change the city dropdown.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function getCity(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getcity.php",
            data:'country='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#city").html(data);
            }
        });getsite();
    }

    function getSite(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getsite.php",
            data:'city='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#site").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Selects:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" onChange="getCity(this.value);" required>
```

and

```
<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city" onChange="getSite(this.value);" required>
```

Comment: *" ...but the "site" dropdown isn't populate UNLESS I manually change the city dropdown"* - Because that's how it was programmed: `id="city" onChange="getSite(this.value);"`, the `getSite` method changes the HTML of `#site`: `$("#site").html(data)`.

Comment: What is the behavior that you are expecting?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Actually he is calling getSite() after ajax call in getCity().

Comment: It's `getsite()` vs `getSite()`.

Comment: @scrappedcola I would like that when I select a country on the countries dropdown, the city dropdown get the right values (already does) and also the third dropdown (sites). The third one only gets the values if I change the city dropdown manually. Example: I select England, I get the city dropdown automatically filled with the first value, lets say: London but the third dropdown doesn't show anything. If I swap London to Manchester and then back to London, I get the expected values on that third dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** There are three mistakes in the `javascript`.

**1.** Start by invoking the right function; edit the line:

```
        });getsite();
```

to:

```
        });getSite();
```

**2.** Then, make sure you pass the city name as a parameter:

```
        });getSite($("#city").val());
```

or edit the function itself to look it up before firing the ajax request, by modifying this line:

```
        data:'city='+val,
```

to become:

```
        data:'city='+$("#city").val(),
```

**3.** As it is, `getSite()` is called right after the ajax request is made, *before* the results are returned. It has to be moved inside the `success` function:

```
        success: function(data){
            $("#city").html(data);
            getSite($("#city").val());
        }
    });
```

**Test:** The following code sample does what is asked (I didn't bother to recreate the `php` file):

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<script>
    function getCity(val) {
        var data = '<option value="London">London</option><option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>"';
        $("#city").html(data);
        getSite($("#city").val());
    }
    function getSite(val) {
        if (val == 'London') {
            var data = '<option value="Westminster Abbey">Westminster Abbey</option><option value="Piccadilly Circus">Piccadilly Circus</option>"';
        } else if (val == 'Manchester') {
            var data = '<option value="Old Trafford">Old Trafford</option><option value="Heaton Park">Heaton Park</option>"';
        }
        $("#site").html(data);
    }
</script>

Country:<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" onChange="getCity(this.value);" required>
    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
</select>
City: <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city" onChange="getSite(this.value);" required></select>
Site: <select class="form-control" name="site" id="site" required></select>
</body></html>
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'm a network engineer, not a programmer. If you can elaborate on how I could solve the issue, it will be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: @FM86 Found a further mistake in your code and added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem solved.

I changed a little bit the approach:

script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#country').on('change',function(){
            var countryID = $(this).val();
            if(countryID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'getcountrycitysite.php',
                    data:'country='+countryID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#city').html(html);
                        $('#site').html('<option value="">Select city first</option>');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
                $('#site').html('<option value="">Select city first</option>');
            }
        });

        $('#city').on('change',function(){
            var cityID = $(this).val();
            if(cityID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'getcountrycitysite.php',
                    data:'city='+cityID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#site').html(html);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#site').html('<option value="">Select city first</option>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

(...)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Country</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required>
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
      <?php
         require_once ("settings.php");

         $link = @mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
         $query = "SELECT * FROM country";

         if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
             $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 echo '<option value = '.$row["id"].'>'.$row["country"].'</option>';
             }
         } else {
             echo "blah";
         }

         mysqli_close($link);
         ?>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>City</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city" required>
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Site</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="site" id="site" required>
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

(...)

As you see I removed the onChange="getCity(this.value); on the selects and created a single php script to get city and site values:

```
<?php
require_once("settings.php");

if (isset($_POST["country"]) && !empty($_POST["country"])) {

    $link       = @mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    $query      = 'SELECT * FROM city WHERE idcountry = ' . $_POST["country"];
    $resultcity = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($resultcity);


    if ($rowcnt > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select City</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcity)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['city'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">City not Available</option>';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["city"])) {

    $link       = @mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    $query      = 'SELECT * FROM site WHERE idcity = ' . $_POST["city"];
    $resultsite = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $rowcnt = mysqli_num_rows($resultsite);


    if ($rowcnt > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select site</option>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsite)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['site'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Site not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nfosci/input-fetcher-dropdown   provides an option to resolve this problem.